# How to click on required coordinates of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, google-chrome-extension

This is the code I used in selenium. I found the coordinates of the object using the chrome plugin-coordinates.  It has frame of ref as the top left corner of the page. but when I used those coordinates in the following line of code, the click is happening elsewhere. Where is the frame of reference in this case?. How to click in the accurate location?

```
Actions uploadbtn = new Actions(BaseClass.driver);
     uploadbtn.moveToElement(Filter.FilterApplied(), 200, 0).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Did you look at `.moveToElement()` in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Where is the frame of reference in this case?

Assuming `Filter.FilterApplied()` is a WebElement, the frame of reference is the top left corner of that element.

> "How to click in the accurate location?

Use a WebElement whose top left corner is the top left corner of the page.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(BaseClass.driver); //You named this uploadbtn, but this doesn't really represent a button
actions.moveToElement(SomeEntirePageElement, 200, 0).click().build().perform();
```

Or better yet, why not just click the element without worrying about coordinates, since clicking by coordinates is probably going to cause maintenance nightmares?

```
Filter.FilterApplied().click();
//Or are you trying to click an Upload button? If so, use a selctor for that button and click that.
```